# difference between git pull --rebase and git rebase branch

Tags: git, github, version-control, gitlab, versioning

what is the difference between

- git pull --rebase
- git rebase origin/nameOfBranch

and when must use one over the other

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+difference+pull+rebase

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is that `git pull` does two things:

- `fetch` and
- `merge` (or `rebase`, since you give it the `--rebase` argument)

On the other hand, `git rebase` does only the rebase, not the fetch.

Comment: if I type **git pull --rebase** does it mean I made **fetch+merge+rebase** (as pull is a combination of fetch and merge) ?

Comment: @bohitbti No, it does a rebase instead of a merge.

Comment: in that case I should have used git rebase directly, no ?
so which are the cases should I use
1) git pull 'only', 2) git rebase 'only', 3) git pull --rebase

Comment: @bohitbti That depends on whether you want to do the fetch or not. Remember that a fetch is the way to get new commits from the remote repository. `origin/nameOfBranch` is only changed by a fetch operation. A simple rebase will never move `origin/nameOfBranch`.

Comment: I guess I must make a fetch before pushing my commit ?

Comment: what is the 'i' param added in some command

Comment: *I guess I must make a fetch before pushing my commit?* I would consider that best practice, but technically it is not required.

Comment: *what is the 'i' param added in some command?* That is a new question ;-)